# Python Mock and Unit test best practices

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I am very new to Python world and learning my way in it. I have Java and C# background and in Java/C# unit testing approach is very clear. We have a class under test and we inject all the mocked dependency with expectations to test code.

like:

Car class with a service fuelLevel
Test case: Car is showing low fuel indication, we can write a test.

```
    FuelLevelService fsMock = mock(FuelLevelService .class);
    when(fsMock.getLevel()).thenReturn(LOW);
    Car car = Car(fsMock)
    car.start()
    assertTrue(car.warningIndicator());
    assertTrue(car.warning().contains("Fuel level low Warning"));
```

In python i have read we can use monkey patching to set the dependent objects and we can test.

```
    @mock.patch('models.fuel_service.getLevel')
    def test_main(self, fuel_service):
        fuel_service.return_value = 'LOW'
        Car car = Car(fuel_service)
        car.start()
        self.assertEqual(car.warningIndicator(), True)
```

I was going to use this approach. But my colleagues have rejected this idea and are proposing to instantiate the actual objects (FuellevelService) and set its value. I find it to be very cumbersome and not needed as in mock also we can do the same with just our expectations.

I am currently struggling to understand if i am wrong or in python my colleagues approach is regarded better pattern.

*Above i have given a simple example. In our project to create an instance object and setting its value is 10-25 lines of code [don't ask me why but that is how it is :)]  To create this object and set a value so it returns that same value looks extra maintenance to me. For this approach to create dependent object we will have many py files in module.

Another point is we are here only testing class under test (not dependency service class), class under test which will react on the returned value of the dependency service. We can can have both negative and positive tests to cover class under test.

For dependency service class in same way it should have its own tests to validate all its scenarios separability. So it will be class under test there. By doing this we will have clear separation and test will fail where there is bug.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use mocks if creating the real objects are inconvenient/cumbersome to create (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object#Reasons_for_use)).

If, as you allude to in your question, you can create the real instance cheaply, and set its value easily, there's no real need for a mock.

Additionally, you don't have any guarantee that the mock behaves like the real implementation, so your test might test... something, but not necessarily how your code will really behave in production. Using the production class is preferable.

Comment: Just to add another reason to use the real class instance instead of a mock:  if your mock tests for very specific behavior and you alter your real class, you may miss something unexpected as you test the mock object, even if you were thorough when first setting up the tests. There's no reason take that risk if you don't need to.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see. Actually in our case creating real object is long process (above is a simple example), we have to create new separate py files just for creating this real object. It maintenance looks extra effort to me. If all we need is a method returning a simple value (why to write a new method with 10-25 lines of code). Remember we are testing class under test not this dependency here. For this dependency service we should have separate tests.